# Different template for different group

Tags: product, template, bundled-product

I'm looking for a way to load a template (.phtml) per group. In this case i want to show all options to a logged in user for a bundle product. Other users should be able to see the options but they can not order.

At this moment i am using this code to detect the user group. A user with groupId == 2 will be shown the normal template. But how do i replace the 'Get a different template' text with an actual template? At this moment i am just showing text instead off a template.

```
    <?php
            $login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); //Check if User is Logged In
            if($login)
            {
                $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); //Get Customers Group ID
                if($groupId == 2) //2
                {
                echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);
                }

            }
            else {
                echo ('Get a different template with name options-new.phtml');
            }               
            ?>
```

FYI: I placed this code in the wrapper.phtml and i am trying to show bundled options.